# Setting up Suexec on apache on Godaddy Virtual private hosting

Tags: php, apache-2.2, centos, suexec, suphp

I have recently purchased Godaddy VPS (Virtual Private Server) with their custom control panel and CentOS 5.4

From their control panel I am able to add domains to the server with their own user and directory.

Example:- Domain: Dummy.com
          User to control the domain "dummy.com": dummyuser
          Directory for the user : "/home/dummyuser/public_html/"

I was installing wordpress on the domain "dummy.com", but the wordpress installer was unable to write the config file to the directory. After some research I realised that this was because of the fact that apache was the user/owner running the apache webserver and it fetched the files from "dummyuser"'s diretory to execute them as the user "apache" instead of the owner of the file.

However I overcame the problem of writing to the directory by chmod 777 on the directory so apache was able to write to that directory. But now, here was another problem. "Apache" became the owner of the files it wrote or uploaded to the "dummyuser" directory which meant that "dummyuser" can not edit/delete/update files created in its own directory by "apache". So this was a real mess. But I deleted the files by using the chown -R username /home/username command to change the files owners/groups.

I want to install suexec so that each user such as "dummyuser" is able to execute its own scripts under its own username using Apache Webserver. This will allow "dummyuser" to write to its own directory without a problem and also will be the owner of the files it writes to the directory.

I have tried all the links out there, every forum and every place, but I have failed to install suexec. I understand that some of you may get frustrated by just reading this really long explanation but I hope that you also can understand how frustrated I am right now that I actually wrote this whole question after trying to install suexec for last 6 days.

I am able to use ssh. I am looking for someone to post a step by step guide to installing suexec and I want to configure it for "/home/[user]/public_html" directory where user is the username for the domain user.CentOS 5.4 is Operating System being used (with apache, mysql preinstalled).

If you know other ways to tackle this problem, then please do suggest them (I will really appreciate it).

Please do not copy and paste the instructions from other sites because I have tried about 20 different ways to install suexec but all of them failed.

I really need an a though response with step by step [working] instructions.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

It require you to be a experienced linux administrator to following the link

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/suexec.html#install

Otherwise, I strongly recommend you to ask GoDaddy support to do the job for you. Submit a support ticket there.

Comment: Hi, I really want to do this myself so I know what I am doing and its about personal experience and my keenness to expertize in this area. So please can anyone write a step by step guide for commands for me to enter through ssh to install and configure suexec. 

Thanks

Comment: It's not simple as a step by step guide. If you install it through ssh, you can somehow conflict with the control panel. For example, some configuration you wrote directly to apache httpd may not reflect on the control panel. So it is required to analyze how your vps and it's control panel is structured and install accordingly. A guide can take you there or it will break your server.

Comment: Is there no way I can do this! Please try to understand.

What if I give you access to my server for a while by giving you a user name and pass and root access and then you could see what works with my vps and after that you can write a guide for that.

Then I can re-provision the server and follow your guide.